# Tooltip with links JavaScript

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple way to implement a tooltip with links inside? Without using Jquery ui?

Title attribute doesn't parse the href element well, when I use Jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

yes, with CSS, see simple example http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp